# Is it possible to create an alias for a drive name on Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, external-hard-drive, osx-mavericks

I have an external drive that I now reference via:

```
/Volumes/FreeAgent Goflex Drive/
```

I wish to rename this to something that doesn't have spaces, as AngularJS's `lite-server` doesn't work on paths with spaces in them (somehow), but I also don't want to change the actual name, because I have many references that use this exact name.

Is there any way I can setup an alias, so that I can access the drive's contents via, for example:

```
/Volumes/Ext1/
```

I remember there being something similar on Linux, but I can't recall how to do this, exactly.

Comment: If your rights are sufficient, I don't think OSX stops you from creating a symlink with whatever name you like. It's just FreeBSD after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symbolic link to it, with something like:

```
ln -s "/Volumes/FreeAgent Goflex Drive" /Volumes/FreeAgent-Goflex-Drive
```

Comment: fuck macos sucks ...